# Usage of reflection in Android a bad design?

Tags: java, android, reflection

I am new in Android development. I have a question regarding the usage of Reflection APIs in Android.

As for example I can write some code like this to connect Bluetooth:

```
     try {
        Method connectMethod = proxy.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("connect", BluetoothDevice.class);
        if(!((Boolean) connectMethod.invoke(proxy, device))){
            Log.i(TAG, "Unable to start connection");
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Connection Successful");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to reflect android.bluetooth.BluetoothPan", e);
    }
```

Similarly other APIs can be used to set tethering and do other stuffs. 
These functions (like set tethering) are supposed to be done from the Setting application in phone by a user.

These are my questions ?

1. Is it not recommended to use reflection in android development?
2. If I create custom permissions for those functions and add to user permissions then is it supported by design ? Because there is no special permission (user permission) required for reflection API access.
3. As per android design pattern, is it a taboo to use reflection APIs ?

Comment: If you use it to get access to methods and field you normally would not have access it is definitely putting you on thin ice.

Comment: @Henry : Thanks for your reply.  But can you explain with some example. Like suppose I am developing one app which only works with tethering, so every time the user need to go to Settings and start tethering manually.  If I do the same job using reflection am I on "thin ice" ??

Comment: Yes, because you are doing something the API designers do not support. It may break with every little version upgrade.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reflection is kind of slow. Although on newer Android versions it is not that bad. The big problem with reflection is that the classes you use might change and you won't notice because the compiler does not know. This is especially bad, when you use it to access third party code that is not under your control or internal apis that are not meant for public consumption. As such it is considered bad practice in general but even more so on Android because of the performance implications. As a rule I would never do anything with reflection that can be done without it.

Answer (score 1):

1) Reflection is to be avoided if possible. It's very hacky, very brittle (breaks easily on updates), hard to maintain and often gets you into bad situations by skipping important validation/setup steps. Sometimes it is the only solution - these situations are quite rare and don't often come up in stock Android development.

2) You can add custom user permissions in Android but I don't see how that is relevant here. The user will have no idea what reflection is or when it is used. Permissions should be used for when you need to ask the user for authorisation for certain actions (using location, making calls, etc).

3) Somewhat, yes. Reflection should be avoided if at all possible, for the reasons listed above.

Answer (score -1):

1. It is good to know the concept on when or where to use reflections in android development
2. Yes it will be supported by design.
3. As per android design pattern it still depends on the feature or the app that you would be doing to use reflection APIs, if it is needed then we should use it.